# Prove the set ${x \in \ell^{1} : |x_{1}| < \sum _{n=2}^{\infty}|x_{n}|2^{-n}}$is open

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Prove the set of ${x \in \ell^{1} : |x_{1}| < \sum _{n=2}^{\infty}|x_{n}|2^{-n}}$ is open, where $\ell^{1}$ is the set of all sequences with $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}| < \infty$. I know that if I can find a continous function from $\ell^1$ to the real numbers with the pre image being equal to this set then I'm done I'm just having trouble finding the function.

Comment: You're very close - consider the map $\ell^1\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $(x_1,\ldots)\mapsto(|x_1|,\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2^{-n}|x_n|)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking $x\in l^1$ be an element in this set. Let $a = \sum_{n=2}^\infty |x_n| 2^{-n} -|x_1| > 0$. We prove that the ball $B_b(x)$ is contained in this set for any $0 < b < a$. Indeed, for any $y \in B_b(x)$, we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |y_n -x_n| < b$. We have
$$|y_1| \leq |x_1-y_1| + |x_1| < b-\sum_{n=2}^\infty |x_n-y_n| + \sum_{n=2}^\infty |x_n| 2^{-n} -a.$$
Using the inequality $|x_n| \leq |y_n| + |x_n -y_n|$ we get
$$|y_1| < \sum_{n=2}^\infty |y_n| 2^{-n} + b -a -\sum_{n=2}^\infty |x_n-y_n| (1 -2^{-n}) < \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} |y_n| 2^{-n},$$
since $b < a$. Hence $y$ belongs to this set.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, take $f:l_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{|x_n|}{2^n} - |x_1|$.  Then $f$ is continuous and so $f^{-1}(0, \infty)$, the set in question, is open since the inverse image of any open set by a continuous function is open.